# Extracting texts from array of cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have been trying to pull particular data from cells to arrange it in a 'return/enter' separated values. I did succeed to an extent using excel formulas but need your help to make it better. I believe Excel VBA would be great here.. To make things clear for you, I am sharing a sample excel file using the below link. It shows what I have tried. It also explain the data in the shared excel file.

http://www.filedropper.com/book1_12
Follow the link and click "Download This File"

Comment: Show us what you have tried, and where you have run into problems, so we can help you fix it.

Comment: In addition, to encourage answers, I suggest you take a look at this article about [discouraging screenshots of code and data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) and put data in your question that can be copied into a worksheet.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will be happy to share what I have tried using the excel formulas. Being new here; I am not sure how to display it in a proper manner. Is there any way I could attach my excel file here?(small file 12KB). Or am I allowed to add another image(I know its not the best way)

Comment: Consider the below in cell A4.  East France
xxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxx

,South America
xxxxx
xxxxxxxx
  
[  Formula to get "East France" : LEFT(A4,FIND("enter/return",A4))  ]
[  Formula to get "South America" : LEFT(RIGHT(A4,LEN(A4)-FIND(",",A4)),FIND("enter/return",RIGHT(A4,LEN(A4)-FIND(",",A4))))  ]
Then I Concatenate the result from the above formula. I am not able to get the result if there are more than two countries.

Comment: A few methods:  You can use a [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). After you paste the results into your question, you need to use the `Code Sample  {...}` tool in the menu bar to format it correctly.  Or you can upload your file to a public sharing site, and post a link.  Do this by editing your original question.

Comment: Another issue is that the screenshot may not represent your data properly.  For example, wordwrapping can be a result of column width, or of embedded `lf` tokens.

Comment: Edited the question and shared a sample excel file using public sharing site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now with the sample file, a VBA solution is simplest.

- For speed, we do the "work" in vba arrays rather than have multiple read/write of the worksheet
- we also are using fully qualified variables; good practice and added flexibility for future maintenance
- Read in the range to be processed
- prepend a comma to the first line
- split each entry on the linefeed
- Construct a results string, testing for lines that start with a comma
- write the resultant string to a vba "results" array.
- write the resultant array back to the worksheet

  - you may need to add some formatting of the results to the code.

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub ExtrCountries()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim I As Long
    Dim V As Variant, W As Variant
    Dim S As String


Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Sheet1")
With wsSrc
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    Set rRes = .Cells(2, 2)
End With

ReDim vRes(1 To UBound(vSrc, 1), 1 To UBound(vSrc, 2))

For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    V = Split("," & vSrc(I, 1), vbLf)
    S = ""
    For Each W In V
        If Left(W, 1) = "," Then
            S = S & vbLf & Mid(W, 2)
        End If
    Next W
    vRes(I, 1) = Mid(S, 2)
Next I

Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1), UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.ClearContents
    .Rows(1) = "DESIRED"
    .Value = vRes
'Can set some formatting options if desired
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do what you are wanting:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'change the name of the sheet above to the Sheet you are using
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row on Column A
For x = 1 To LastRow 'loop from row 1 to last
    For i = 1 To Len(ws.Cells(x, 1).Value) 'check length of characters in cell
        If ws.Cells(x, 1).Characters(i, 1).Font.FontStyle = "Bold" Then 'check if content is bold
            ValueToCopy = Mid(ws.Cells(x, 1), i, 1) 'get the bold character
            ws.Cells(x, 2).Value = ws.Cells(x, 2).Value & ValueToCopy 'place the character on Column B
        End If
    Next i
Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am sorry for the miscommunication, but the BOLD was just a representation to show which character I want in the column B. The characters are not actually Bold.

Comment: Is there a pattern to it? is is always four characters in a single line?

Comment: I'm guessing here, but is it always the first line in Column A, and then the next line you want starts with a comma?

Comment: Yes you are correct. Characters to be extracted could be of any length. There also might be spaces between them. **"AB C D"**.  Each line is separated by return/enter.

Comment: Hello Xabier, edited the original question and shared a sample excel file to make things clear.